# Formalizing intuition on real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R_+$ be a function such that:

1. $\int f(u)du=1$;
2. It is differentiable on its support $[0,\infty)$;
3. It is bounded (there is $c_1>0: \lvert f\rvert \leq c_1$);
4. There is $v>1$ such that for some $C,L>0$ we have $f(u)\leq Cu^{-v}$ for all
   $u>L$;
5. Its derivatives are nonpositive ($f'\leq 0$) on $[0,\infty)$.

From 1 and 2, I think that we can find $u_0>0$ such that $\int_0^{u_0}f(u)du=\int_{u_0}^\infty f(u)du$. Is there such result on real analysis?

From 5, the function is monotone decreasing. I believe that the following holds:
$$\int_0^{u_0}f(u)du\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\left \lceil{u_0}\right \rceil }\int_{i-1}^if(u)du\leq \left \lceil{u_0}\right \rceil \int_0^1f(u)d(u)$$

So if I want to give an upper bound for $\int_0^{\infty}f(u)du$, I can directly bound $2\left \lceil{u_0}\right \rceil \int_0^1f(u)d(u)$ for some $u_0>0$.

Do these ideas make sense?

Comment: 1. alone suffices to know that there exists $u_0>0$ s.t. $\int_0^{u_0} f(u)\mathrm du=\int_{u_0}^\infty f(u)\mathrm du$, because the integral of a function is a (absolutely) continuous function, therefore you can use the squeeze theorem on $x\in\mathrm R\mapsto\int_0^x f(u)\mathrm du$.

Comment: I think you made a typo in your sum, the bounds of the integral should be $(i-1), i$, not $0, i$. Plus, 5. contradicts $f\geq 0$ by mean inequality.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Then any $u_0>0$ satisfies the equality.

Comment: Well, $d_2$ has to be zero for 5. to be consistent with the other assumptions. Also, we were discussing the possibility that $f$ could be zero on $[0,\infty)$ if this weren't its support.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I did not even realise that one...

Comment: The boundedness holds on the support $[0,\infty)$. It was a typo. In these assumptions, I wanted to characterize the gaussian function $f(u)=2(\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1}\exp\{-u^2/2\}1_{[0,\infty)}(u)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Well yes, the squeeze theorem only applies to functions that have different values at the bounds.